# Return list of list from list of strings that have lists in them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings where the strings have lists. I want to return a list of lists.

Here is what I might start with:

```
old_list = ['[1,2,m]','[4.1,3.5,5]','[x,y,z]', '["t","u","v"]']
```

Here is what I would want:

```
new_list = [[1,2,'m'],[4.1,3.5,5],['x','y','z'],['t','u','v']]
```

Comment: Why do you have quotes around the string elements sometimes, but not other times? Can you fix the source so it adds the quotes consistently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a list of lists from a list of strings with lists in the strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509445/how-to-return-a-list-of-lists-from-a-list-of-strings-with-lists-in-the-strings)

Comment: It wasn't fully answered there

Comment: And that is a reason to re-post it? I think you are missing the point of how stackoverflow works.

Comment: Sharing information on coding is not the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a case where you have to build your own hammer, so to speak. Use a combination of [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) where you can, and then build a custom parser where you can't. You may need to add more cases as needed.

```
from ast import literal_eval

old_list = ['[1,2,m]','[4.1,3.5,5]','[x,y,z]', '["t","u","v"]']

def hierarchical_convert(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            return(s)

new_lst = []
for s in old_list:
    try:
        out = literal_eval(s)
    except ValueError: #need to split on comma ourselves, and invoke custom parsing
        out = [hierarchical_convert(item) for item in s[1:-1].split(',')]
    new_lst.append(out)


print(new_lst)
#Output
[[1, 2, 'm'], [4.1, 3.5, 5], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['t', 'u', 'v']]
```

Comment: answer to a question like this can only be a hack. I appreciate the passes, increasing the hack level, to improve the chance of parsing it right. Excellent answer.